# Where should I run firebase init and what is a source control root in a Cloud Functions project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm adding a custom authentication system to my app using Firebase CLI. This is where I'm at:

> Initialize a Firebase project
>
> Many common tasks performed using the
> CLI, such as deploying to a Firebase project, require a **project**
> **directory**. You establish a project directory using the `firebase init`
> command. A project directory is usually the same directory as your
> source control root, and after running `firebase init`, the directory
> contains a `firebase.json` configuration file.
>
> To initialize a new Firebase project, run the following command from
> within your app's directory:
>
> `firebase init`

[Firebase CLI reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#linux)

I tried googling "initialize firebase source control root directory" and "source control root directory meaning" and got mixed results. The first search results tell you that you should run `firebase init` in the same directory as your source control root but not what it actually is. The second results tell you what a root directory is in linux, what goes in source control and something about Git. I'm more confused after doing research than before.

Where should I run `firebase init`?

Is it `/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/`

`/project/app/`

`/project/app/src/`

or none of the above?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to run the `firebase init` command in the Firebase CLI, if you intend to use other commands (such as `firebase deploy`) in the CLI too.

If you're only building an Android app with Firebase and not using other services that require the CLI (such as Firebase Hosting or Cloud Functions), it is unlikely that you ened to run `firebase init`.

Comment: I intend to use Cloud Functions to run my backend code without managing servers

Comment: In that case the Cloud Functions mention in your title is a meaningless distraction. I removed it, but recommend paying closer attention to that yourself going forward. You'll typically run `firebase init` in the directory where your Cloud Functions source code is one level deeper (usually in a `functions` subdirectory). So in my Android+Functions projects I often have a "project root" directory (where I run `firebase init`) and the under that I have `android` for the Android `app`, and `functions` for the Cloud Functions code.